# Do a return of multiple create function Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Just finished a `php artisan make:auth`, In `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` lies the default create function:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

I have added in the view of the same page of this default view (`/register`) a birthdate from another model. How do I insert a new create function in the same default create function?

[image]

```
UserInformation::create([
    'user_id' => ???
    'birth_date' => $data['birth_dae']
]);
```

How can I connect this to the above `return` statement and how will I able to get the newly created `id` from the `User` and pass it to the `user_id` of `UserInformation`?

My Idea so far:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return [
        User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]),
        UserInformation::create([
        'user_id' => ??? // should be the same as the id of the created user
        'birth_date' => $data['birth_date'],
        'color' => "blue"
        ])
    ];
}
```

Tried doing something like this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $data['name'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->password = Hash::make($data['password']);
    $user->save();

    $user_id = $user->id;

    $user_info = new UserInformation;
    $user_info->user_id = $user_id;
    $user_info->birth_date = $data['birth_date'];
    $user_info->color = "blue";
    $user_info->save();

    return view('home');
}
```

But still returns this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must
>   implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable,
>   instance of Illuminate\View\View given

**EDIT:**

A good friend of mine recommended this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'pasword' => Hash::make($data["password"])
    ]);

    UserInformation::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'birth_date' => $data['birth_date'],
        'color' => 'blue'
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```

And in my UserInformation model:

```
protected $fillable = ["user_id", "birth_date", "color"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, `return Model::create(...);` will simply return `true` or `false` (or die on an error) depending on the result of the `create()` function, so we can adjust the code to handle this. Try the following:

```
protected function create(array $data){
  \DB::beginTransaction();

  try {
    $user = User::create([
      "name" => $data["name"],
      "email" => $data["email"],
      "password" => Hash::make($data["password"])
    ]);

    $userInformation = UserInformation::create([
      "user_id" => $user->id,
      "birth_date" => $data["birth_date"],
      "color" => "blue"
    ]);
  } catch(\Exception $ex){
    \DB::rollBack();
    \Log::error("Error creating User and UserInformation: ".$ex->getMessage());

    return false;
  }

  \DB::commit();

  return true;
}
```

By setting `$user` to the result of `User::create()`, you can use `$user->id` in the subsequent `UserInformation::create()`. Also, I recommend using transactions when saving dependent records. If `User::create()` is successful, and `UserInformation::create()` fails, you won't end up with a `User` that has no `UserInformation`, as the whole transaction is rolled-back on fail, and persisted to the database on success.

Comment: After trying to do all your recommendation which I can appreciate for its code clarity. I have experienced this error: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, boolean given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\capstone-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35`

Comment: Ah, likely need to change `return true` to `return $user;`. And maybe `return false` to `return null`. I generally roll my own auth logic (Sentinel, custom controllers), so I'm not too familiar with this implementation.

Comment: Tried possible returns but still got this error. But thanks for the idea though.

Comment: The **exact** same error? You shouldn't get `boolean given` if you return `$user`... It's not a `boolean`, but a `User` model. Does your `User` model implement `Authenticatable`? If you use `return $user;`, it _should_ work...

Comment: Yes tried it again and still having this error: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, boolean given`, as it it is expecting another type of argument.

Comment: edited my posts, don't know why it works in such manner that the Authenticatable is not throwing an exception this time.

Comment: I said "*if you return `$user` ...*" in my comment, and I thought you implemented that. Your edit has `return $user;` and you say it's working... I'm confused, but I _think_ you figured it out?

Comment: Yes don't get me wrong I tried doing that, and bunch of workarounds. It is only that moment when I tried what I posted in the edit section, if finally worked.

Comment: Ah ok ok. Likely a combination of setting your `$fillable` array. If that was throwing an error, and you were using my code, it would have been caught and returning `false`, which is (obviously) a `boolean`.